# How to fix "Exception: Limit Exceeded" error when trying to upload an image to Graph API using Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, google-apps-script, facebook-marketing-api

I am using Facebook [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-image) to create a Facebook ads campaign with Google Apps Script.

I need to upload an image to my Facebook ad account. I have already tried to use the image bytes as a Base64 UTF-8 string, but when I call the API I get:

> Exception: Limit Exceeded: URLFetch URL Length.

Basically, the string is too long.

I am using the following code:

```
function uploadTest2() {
  var image_id = 'blabla';
  var image_blob = DriveApp.getFileById(image_id).getBlob();
  var input = image_blob.getBytes();
  var docImg = Utilities.base64Encode(input);
  
  var account_id = '1111111111111';
  var facebookUrl = 
    'https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0' +
    '/act_' + account_id +
    '/adimages?bytes=' + docImg +
    '&access_token=' + TOKEN;
  Logger.log(facebookUrl);

  //var encodedFacebookUrl = encodeURI(facebookUrl);
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post'
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(facebookUrl, options);
  var results = JSON.parse(response);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

The image does not exceed 5MB and I have already check the bytes string with an online decoder to verify it.

Do you have any idea on how to use the image URL directly in the post request?

---

The second version of the code:

```
function uploadTest2() {
  var image_id = 'blabla';
  var image_blob = DriveApp.getFileById(image_id).getBlob();
  var input = image_blob.getBytes();
  var docImg = Utilities.base64Encode(input);
  
  var account_id = '1111111111111';
  var facebookUrl = 
    'https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0' +
    '/act_' + account_id +
//    '/adimages?bytes=' + encodedImage +
//    '&access_token=' + TOKEN;
    '/adimages?access_token=' + TOKEN;
  Logger.log(facebookUrl);

  //var encodedFacebookUrl = encodeURI(facebookUrl);
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : image_blob
  }; 

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(facebookUrl, options);
  var results = JSON.parse(response);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

Comment: You should include the relevant code you wrote in the question (if there is any), describe what you already tried to do to achieve the desired result or at least make it clear that you did [sufficient amount of research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) prior to posting. Questions that do not follow this guideline tend to get closed and deleted. Please see [“How to Ask”](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: + see [quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) for `UrlFetchApp`: URL Fetch URL length 2kB / call. Also note that the post body size should be under 50MB.

Comment: Hi ! Could you please provide a sample code *with no sensitive data* with the sample request you are trying to achieve (use a fake url with the same length so that no sensitive data is exposed)? Thanks ! :D

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your suggestions @OlegValter! I have modified my answer to make it clearer showing some of the work I have already done.

Comment: @NebuaGinetteSiani - thank you for responding and updating your question! We will certainly take a look (albeit we usually can dechiper what's going on, it is much easier to work with now that we have a code sample at hand :) ) and if anyone can answer we will add info here

Comment: Have you tried adding the ```image_blob``` as the **payload** in **options** as ```var options = {'method' : 'post', 'payload' : image_blob};```? This is better shown in the [UrlFetchApp advanced parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params). Let me know if that solves your issue.

Comment: Hi @MateoRandwolf! Thank you for your help! :D I added the payload you suggested and I modified the **facebookUrl** removing the bytes portions of it, but it did not upload the image. Do you think I should modify the url differently?

Comment: @NebuaGinetteSiani - when you say "did not upload", what error code, if any, is returned from Graph API?

Comment: @OlegValter - I got no error, but the **response** is empty and, when I look at the media in my facebook ad account, the photo I tried to upload is not there.

Comment: @NebuaGinetteSiani - hm, could we see the updated code (please, do not replace the old one, just append it as a separate section separated by three dashes in markup)?

Comment: @OlegValter - I updated the question with the modified code :)

Comment: @NebuaGinetteSiani - thank you for updating the question - I see now that you are trying to send the `Blob` instance to the API via `image_blob` (although the blob may be converted under the hood, I am not sure), try sending the base64-encoded bytes, `docImg` that is. The rest seems correct. Side note: you don't have to comment about updating, we are watching :) Joking aside, the "follow" feature lets us instantly see whether a change is made

Comment: @OlegValter and @MateoRandwolf - Thank you so much for your help!! Finally I used the following and **it worked** - `var options = {'method' : 'post', 'contentType': 'application/json', 'payload': JSON.stringify({"bytes": docImg,"name" : 'Test'})}; ` :D

Comment: @NebuaGinetteSiani - glad it worked, don't mention :)

Comment: As you have solved the issue, I have formalised my and your comments into an answer so that other users with similar problems can find the solution easier. This answer is being posted as community wiki as a great part of the work to obtain the answer was on the original poster side. :D

Comment: @MateoRandwolf - was deferring out of laziness to do so, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make a post request of an image with `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` you must provide the method, payload (i.e the body you want to `POST`) and sometimes the content type (if what we are passing is not a JavaScript object).

If you want to pass a `base64Encode` object obtained from a blob you should stringify this JSON object.

What the original poster was missing was to pass the payload and after my contribution, they finally solved the issue by editing the options variable such as:

```
var options = {
   'method' : 'post',
   'contentType': 'application/json',
   'payload': JSON.stringify({"bytes": docImg,"name" : 'Test'})};
   }
```

Documentation reference: [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params).